# How to add time to a digitalclock?

Tags: android, listener, android-recyclerview

I have an app with a `recyclerview` that displays the time ahead in 30 minute intervals.  The first `viewholder` shows `currenttime+30mins`, the next one shows `currenttime+30mins`, etc.

To initialize the recycler view I have an array that stores calendars. Each one holds a time 30 minutes ahead of the last.  I can display these times fine, but the issues arise when I try to update them to sync with the device time.

Using a handler and a runnable I was able to update the entire array, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter once every 1000ms. But this causes issues.  I have an `onClickListener` set for my view holders, and if I tap the view holder at the same time the `recyclerview` is refreshing, then the `onClick` method is ignored.

How can I automatically update my times every minute, without refreshing the entire `recyclerview` every second?  I thought I could use a `digitalclock`, since it automatically updates the time, but I don't know of a way to add 30 minutes to a digital clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my solution was to switch the digital clocks with text views that are scheduled to update every time the system clock changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to implement a background thread that only returns information when a certain condition is reached. This way, your recyclerview will only refresh every minute in a way that shouldn't interact with the rest of your UI.